# Is it possible to create unique username in MySQL using user's first/last name?

Tags: mysql

I have a registration form that collects a user's first and last name. From that I want to create a user name in the format of 'first.last'. However, if a user already exists with that name I want it to add the next available integer to the end i.e. first.last, first.last1, first.last2 etc.

I could do a lookup to find any existence of this but if (edge case) 2 people with the same name join at the same time I want to be sure that 2 of the same usernames aren't created as will use the username for email addresses.

Comment: You should let the user create their own username, and use your method to generate user_display_name instead.

Comment: Do this in the application layer. Doing it in the database is nothing but frustrating for a lack of tools.

Comment: @Ibu didn't want the user to create their own username, so that the email addresses are in the same format.

Comment: @tadman do you know of any examples of how this would be done?

Comment: It's super easy to do it in application layer code, just write a loop. To do the equivalent in MySQL requires writing a fairly complicated stored procedure, and that's something that almost always leads to difficulty down the road because updating that code is not as simple as deploying a new version.

Comment: As much as you want to do this automatically, you'll need an override for names that your system utterly mangles due to assumptions about names. You may also have problems where people don't want certain digits in their names for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply put this constraint

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX new_index_name ON your_table (first_name, last_name);
```